# 3-D continued fractions

Tags: continued-fractions, nt.number-theory

Which theorems from classical theory of continued fractions have 3-(or multi-) dimesional analogs?

Of cause classical one is a periodicity of Klein polyhedra. Probably there are some more...

Comment: You might like the Ph.D. thesis (in Russian, http://www.geometrie.tugraz.at/karpenkov/ ) by Oleg Karpenkov which is all about multidim continued fractions.

Comment: He studied multidimesional Klein model of continued fractions. His thesis contains different theorems concerning this model, but they are not direct analogs of clasical theorem. Though he deeply studied 3-D Gauss-Kuz'min statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) There is 3-D analog of Vahlen's theorem, see http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11006-006-0018-6?LI=true

(2) 3-D isolation theorems and extemal Davenport forms (see Cassels "An Introduction to the Geometry of Numbers" and Swinnerton-Dyer, "On the product of three homogeneous linear forms" Acta Arith., 1971, 18, 371-385). The key role here play numbers $2\cos\frac{2\pi}7$, $2\cos\frac{4\pi}7$, $2\cos\frac{6\pi}7$ (3-D Golden Ratios).

Comment: @Alexey, the modern isolation theorem is due to Lindenstrauss and Weiss - "On Sets Invariant under the Action of the Diagonal Group".